# Accessing form.cleaned data from filter method in DFR

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a filterset based on django_filters in my DRF app that I want to extend with a method based filter:

```
class CarFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name="name")
    vendor = filters.CharFilter(field_name="vendor__name")
    search = filters.CharFilter(method="filter_by_search")

def filter_by_search(queryset, name, value):
        if not self.form.cleaned_data.get("name"):
            #do something
```

Of course this fails as self is no defined in the filter function.

But how can access the cleaned_data from the form from inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial an error I have found that the only way to do this is to replace the default filter_queryset method with my own. I could not find any way to access the request details such as the cleaned form data from within my filter method.

here is an example to raise an error if not at least one of two values is provided, but you could do anything else with it as well.

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        if not (
            self.form.cleaned_data.get("name")
            or self.form.cleaned_data.get("vencor")
        ):
            raise ValidationError("Either 'name' or 'vendor' must be provided.")
```

Important to know is that the QuerySet gets filtered here first, before it calls the filter method for my search filter, that is only called if a "search" parameter was provided.